# Is there a French equivalent of "on a Kick"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, argot, registre-familier

One of the lesser used English definitions of kick is

> 5c: pursuit of an absorbing or obsessive new interest —usually used with on<sup>[1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kick)</sup>

Is there a French equivalent? My French is super rusty, and I did poke around with translators, but I'm guessing that "donner un coup" doesn't carry the same connotation.

Comment: Can you provide examples of sentences that would use that *kick*?

Comment: Example sentence: "Alice is on another Heavy Metal kick" meaning she's been listening to Heavy Metal music a lot lately, but in a week or two she'll have switched to something else, likely back to her "regular" favorites.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the word [*marotte*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marotte), which points to a sudden and invasive passion for something:

> Il s'est mis à la philatélie, et c'est devenu sa marotte, il ne parle plus que de cela.

Answer (score 1):

An  equivalent is "être mordu" (mad on, crazy about), also colloquial.

If a complement must be used the preposition is "de".

- Il est mordu de cinéma. (*adjective*)
- *(variant*) C'est un mordu de/du cinéma. (*nom*)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, one could be on a health kick, [*une mode santé*](https://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/Une+mode+sant%C3%A9).

To get your kicks is *s'amuser* and its synonyms.

Moreover, to be hooked on something (including drugs, not so healthy) or idiomatically on a ____ kick is

### [***être accro***](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/accro) from *accroché*

> (Familier) Qui se rapporte à une personne qui est passionnée par quelqu’un ou par quelque chose.

That which relates to someone with a passion for someone or something, "getting a kick out of it."

> Elles sont toutes accros à ce nouvel acteur.

They are all crazy about this new actor. They're all on a Léo Legrand kick.

> Il est complètement accro de ce nouvel album de BD.

He is so into this new comic book.  He's really on a comic book kick with this new one.

Answer (score 1):

The noun *kif* (from the verb [*kiffer*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiffer)) is slowly moving from suburban to mainstream slang:

> *Il a un nouveau **kif** !*